# Passing class object of WSDL to web service showing null values

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

The user is trying to consume the web service trying to pass list of qualifications but the SOAP throwing an error that the parameters was not supplied.
The main class is as follows:

```
 public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName{ get; set;}
    public List<Qualification> Qualifications { get; set; }
}
 public class Qualification
{
    public string QualificationName { get; set;}
    public DateTime DateOfObtaining{ get; set;}
    public string NameOfUniversity{ get; set; }
}
```

The following is only the part which i have an issue with as i can pass the student object details to the database with no error :

```
 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QualificationName ", qualification.QualificationName );
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfObtaining", qualification.DateOfObtaining);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfUniversity", qualification.NameOfUniversity);
```

All the above are shown null although the user has passed the qualification object with the values:

```
    List<Qualification> AddQualification = new List<Qualification>();
            Qualification qual = new Qualification();
            qual.QualificationName = "Bachelor";
            qual.DateOfObtaining= "20/10/2007";
            qual.NameOfUniversity= "Any text";
          AddQualification.Add(qual);
```

The value of the above qualification object is not viewed in the web service and it is only showing null

```
   Student stud= new Student();
           stud.FirstName =studentName.Text;
            stud.LastName= lastName.Text;
            stud.Qualifications = AddQualification.ToArray();
            service.AddStudent(stud);
```

The Qualification details are displayed in the student objects but it is showing null in qualification object and the SOAP throwing error that QualificationName parameter was not supplied. I have used Serializable for the class and used static for the created object but all the qualification object fields are null. I want to pass the qualification details to the database.

Comment: What does the wsdl show for the AddStudent (that seems to be the crux of the question, the qualifications maybe has no link to a student, so perhaps thats the isssue its a little unclear from the code posted

Comment: It is showing the following fields Web method Name: AddStudent and its type is the Student object. The fields inside the AddStudent are first name, lastname and Qualifications (its data type is ArrayofQualification).

Comment: Well other than its a list and wanted an array.. are you sure the qualification structure is correct

Comment: The Array of Qualification with type qualification has the following fields: NameOfQualification,DateOfObtaining and NameOf Uni.The details of Qualification are viewed in student object through stud.Qualifications which get them from the list of Qualification. The problem is that AddwithValue for qualification object is null for all fields although it is passed by the user

Comment: Yes i am sure about its structure but the strange thing, why it keeps showing them as null. I have tried LINQ. Like the following. Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfQualification", stud.Qualifications.select(r=>r.NameOfQualification); but it is showing it null although Qualifications is not empty even in the web service, the values are viewed in qualifications

Comment: Perhaps its because in your student its named "Qualifcations" not "Qualifications" (and as a dyslexic that was not easy to spot)

Comment: If the spelling is wrong, it is not going to show it. The used qualification field is the same mentioned in student class

Answer (score 0):

I  solved the issue. In case someone come through the same error, the solution is as follows:

```
 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QualificationName ", stud.Qualifications[0].QualificationName );
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfObtaining", stud.Qualifications[0].DateOfObtaining);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfUniversity", stud.Qualifications[0].NameOfUniversity);
```

you can use for loop if you have more than qualification